# Requesting test results after job rejection for the sake of curiosity

Tags: applications

After applying to a job (Software Development) with code samples and a critique of a programming language, I was asked to complete IQ and Personality tests then contact the company. I did so and was told that they were looking for someone with more experience. I was not asked to interview. I'm very curious how I performed on the test. Is it okay to ask for the test results?

Comment: You can always ask. They are unlikely to respond.

Comment: @WesleyLong I had a similar experience ... only worse. I aced the IQ test, then was told I had not qualified. I was damn sure I had 49 out of the 50 questions right, so I thought they were looking for some genius and moved on. A week later, HR called to tell me there had been a "mistake", and they want to interview me. 2 days later, the interview panel mysteriously "went on a business trip" (which is a coward's way of saying "we don't want to interview you"). 2 months later, they called back to "follow up" on the interview, I said "I am out on a business trip" to rub it in and moved on. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask yourself what the worst possible outcome of that would be.

If you can accept the worst possible outcome, then go ahead. If you don't think you can handle the worst possible outcome, then you should probably avoid it, unless the outcome of not making the request is worse than the worst possible outcome of making the request.

In a worst case scenario you prepare to face the worst possible outcome, you've accepted it so it doesn't really matter since you were prepared for it, in the best case scenario you get exactly what you ask for.

A worst case scenario could be, for example:

> They'll completely ignore me.
>
> I'll come off as too needy, thus perhaps ruining my chances in the future with them.
>
> They'll think I'm a potato head.

If you can accept the worst possible outcome, then so be it. You'll either get what you ask for or be ignored. You can think of more extreme scenarios if you wish. I've read remarkable stories of people who have used this method to achieve great things, including eliminating stress, as you'll see that its pointless to stress out on something if you've managed to accept the worst possible outcome. More often than not the worst possible outcome doesn't happen anyway.

This decision process can be applied to pretty much anything. I'm not aiming towards giving you a yes or no question, although I know which answer I'd go for. Good luck!

Comment: "thus perhaps ruining my chances in the future with them".  If asking for feedback means that it ruins my chances in the future, then I say great!  Why would I want to work for a company like that?  BTW, whenever I have had to submit a code sample/HW, I've always asked for feedback and always received it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I agree with you 100%. I was making an example of how some tend to think. This is not a scenario that I'd even consider in this context, but for some it is relevant.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, that comment sounds more hostile than I meant it too.  I think it is a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm very curious how I performed on the test. Is it okay to ask for
>   the test results?

It's always okay to ask for something you want. Be aware however that they are unlikely to share the results with applicants.

While you may just be curious, others sometimes ask about test results with the thought to check for correctness, fairness, etc. or as prelude to argue about the results. No employer wants to get into an argument about such a test.

Since (at least in the US) employers aren't required to share the results of pre-employment tests, and since there is absolutely nothing for the employer to gain by doing so, most likely they won't share them with you. I've only worked at a few companies that required such tests, but none of them would ever share the results.